# Spark: How to keep all columns of a dataframe when performing imputations on a subset of columns?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, data-wrangling

I'm trying to do the imputations below on a subset of columns in my dataframe (`df_data`) but in the process, my resulting dataframe (`imputeDF`) only has the imputed columns.  I wish to keep all of the original columns and add back the imputed columns (and drop the original non-imputed columns).  The imputed dataframe has no id to join back to the `df_data` on and I've researched the `withColumn` function but couldn't get it to work for me.  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
removeAllDF = df_data.na.drop()
imputeDF=df_data['exact_age','lnght_of_resd','acct_tenure_mnth_nbr','acct_ttce_mnth_nbr','tot_promo_amt',               'tot_rev_amt','int_base_pkg_speed','int_mx_elgbl_speed']
for x in imputeDF.columns:
    meanValue = removeAllDF.agg(avg(x)).first()[0]
    print(x, meanValue)
    imputeDF = imputeDF.na.fill(meanValue, (x))
    return imputeDF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
removeAllDF = df_data.na.drop()
imputeDF=df_data['exact_age','lnght_of_resd','acct_tenure_mnth_nbr','acct_ttce_mnth_nbr','tot_promo_amt',               'tot_rev_amt','int_base_pkg_speed','int_mx_elgbl_speed']
for x in imputeDF.columns:
    meanValue = removeAllDF.agg(avg(x)).first()[0]
    print(x, meanValue)
    df_data = df_data.na.fill(meanValue, (x))

df_data.show
```